# Display Profile2 fields in another view

Tags: views, users

How can I display Profile2 fields in a view that has a content type as filter?

Later edit(example):

I have a view which displays a content-type X. I have a profile Y with different fields. I would like to be able to add fields from profile Y to the view which already has fields from content-type X.

Comment: How profile Y is related to content type X? If they are not related, you just have 2 independent lists. What result do you want to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add User relationship, “Content: Author” for example.
After that you will be able to add new relationship “User: Profile” on base of User relationship.

[image]

Now you can add fields from user and user profile. You must not forget that SQL query becomes heavier with each new relationship.

Comment: this somehow works , but it does not as the way i want it. I would like to be able to get all the profiles of type x and also all the content type of type y. I tried your method and it does not work the way i expected it.

Comment: Please, update your question with details.

Comment: just to let you know i have edited the question